# How to get a HTMLelement removed from table column after clicking another column

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I made a directive for showing an icon at the tableheader row when sorting descending or ascending. Now the problem is dat the icon stays active when trying to sort another column. 
right now i use  a hostListener() for the onclick event.

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th appSortIcon *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index" scope="col" [mdbTableSort]="elements" [sortBy]="headElements[i]">{{head | AddSpaceBeforeCapitalLetter | titlecase}}</th>
      </tr>
```

```
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.setSortIconInHostElement();
  }
    const contentForNewIcon = this.renderer.createElement('img');
    this.renderer.addClass(contentForNewIcon, this.elementClassTable);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(contentForNewIcon, 'src', this.currentlySortedByAttribute.value === 'ascending' ? 'assets\\ascIcon.png' : 'assets\\descIcon.png');
}
```

Comment: why do you want to remove the icon? why not use *ngIf to insert it on a specific condition ?

Comment: What do you mean by "staying active?"
I suspect you want to do something to the other icons while clicking another column. Think about what it is and how do you represent the state in a way, that will make it easy for you to decide which icons should be visible. (Perhaps you hold a variable stating the active column, and infer the view from this, and change this as necessary.)

Comment: Well, if i'm sorting 1 column and want to sort another column the ascending or descending icon is still visible on the non-active column. I want to remove that.